# Mysterious errors after updating to Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am getting mysterious console errors when building my application since I updated `Xcode` to **6.1** from **5**. The application works fine, but I'd like to find out what is causing these errors and get rid of them.

Errors are as follows. An exception breakpoint just halts in main, so no real clues there.

```
2014-11-08 09:30:28.800 Finances[5848:1545133] Failed to connect
    (accountSupplementaryDataValue) outlet from (FINAccountEditorWindowController) to
    (NSWindow): missing setter or instance variable
2014-11-08 09:30:28.800 Finances[5848:1545133] Failed to connect (delegate) outlet 
    from (FINAccountEditorWindowController) to (FINAppDelegate): missing setter 
    or instance variable
objc[5848]: Class _NSZombie_OS_dispatch_queue_runloop is implemented in 
    both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I've tracked down the first two. They were referencing outlets with invalid references (hangovers from now deleted code). Obviously Xcode 6 has increased the amount of warnings versus 5. Still haven't worked out what the Zombie error is, although it has now also disappeared.

Comment: I am getting the zombie error too.

Comment: +1 with the zombie error.

Comment: @Rhuantavan did you find the 'zombie error' reason?

Comment: I really can't remember anymore where was I encountering the errors or how/if I solved them, so I can't help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can ignore it? From Greg Parker’s [Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/gparker/status/428388343051587584): “Race in the zombie implementation, maybe? You can ignore it.”

Answer (score -2):

For me when I had those problems I carefully went through them and googled them bit by bit to solve them. Though for some what I did was put the file on a flash drive and delete the file from my computer and then reboot the Xcode and with some the computer too and put the projects back on from the flash drive. If that don't work then maybe try loading them on to a computer with Xcode 5 and seeing if the errors are still there?